# Firebase function to convert YouTube to mp3

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, ffmpeg, google-cloud-functions

I want to deploy to Firebase cloud functions.

However, I get a vague error: “Cannot analyze code” after it goes through the initial pre deploy checks successfully.

But I cannot figure out the problem given the vagueness of the error.

It **looks** right with these requirements:

- receive a POST with JSON body of YouTube videoID as a string
- Download locally using the YouTube download package
- Pipe to the ffmpeg package and save mp3 to the local temp
- Store in default bucket on firestore storage
- Apply make public method to make public

```js
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const ytdl = require('ytdl-core');
const ffmpeg = require('fluent-ffmpeg');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const os = require('os');

admin.initializeApp();

// Set the path to the FFmpeg binary
const ffmpegPath = path.join(__dirname, 'bin', 'ffmpeg');
ffmpeg.setFfmpegPath(ffmpegPath);

exports.audioUrl = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
    if (req.method !== 'POST') {
        res.status(405).send('Method Not Allowed');
        return;
    }

    const videoId = req.body.videoID;
    const videoUrl = `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=${videoId}`;
    const audioPath = path.join(os.tmpdir(), `${videoId}.mp3`);

    try {
        await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            ytdl(videoUrl, { filter: format => format.container === 'mp4' })
                .pipe(ffmpeg())
                .audioCodec('libmp3lame')
                .save(audioPath)
                .on('end', resolve)
                .on('error', reject);
        });

        const bucket = admin.storage().bucket();
        const file = bucket.file(`${videoId}.mp3`);
        await bucket.upload(audioPath, {
            destination: file.name,
            metadata: {
                contentType: 'audio/mp3',
            },
        });

        // Make the file publicly accessible
        await file.makePublic();

        const publicUrl = file.publicUrl();
        res.status(200).send({ url: publicUrl });
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error processing video:', error);
        res.status(500).send('Internal Server Error');
    }
});
```

The following is the `package.json` file which is used to reference the dependencies for the function, as well as the entry point, which I believe just needs to be the name of the filename with the code:

```
{
  "name": "firebase-functions",
  "description": "Firebase Cloud Functions",
  "main": "audioUrl.js", 
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase-admin": "^10.0.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^4.0.0",
    "ytdl-core": "^4.9.1",
    "fluent-ffmpeg": "^2.1.2"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "18"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

(Edit) Here is the error:

```
 deploying functions
✔  functions: Finished running predeploy script.
i  functions: preparing codebase default for deployment
i  functions: ensuring required API cloudfunctions.googleapis.com is enabled...
i  functions: ensuring required API cloudbuild.googleapis.com is enabled...
i  artifactregistry: ensuring required API artifactregistry.googleapis.com is enabled...
✔  functions: required API cloudbuild.googleapis.com is enabled
✔  artifactregistry: required API artifactregistry.googleapis.com is enabled
✔  functions: required API cloudfunctions.googleapis.com is enabled
i  functions: Loading and analyzing source code for codebase default to determine what to deploy
Serving at port 8171

shutdown requested via /__/quitquitquit


Error: Functions codebase could not be analyzed successfully. It may have a syntax or runtime error
```

```
Failed to load function definition from source: FirebaseError: Functions codebase could not be analyzed successfully. It may have a syntax or runtime error
```

I get the same error when running the following:

```
firebase deploy --only functions:audioUrl
```

And I thought I might get more detailed errors using the emulator:

```
firebase emulators:start
```

Under the emulator I had this additional error initially:

```
Your requested "node" version "18" doesn't match your global version "16". Using node@16 from host.
```

Comment: Please edit the question to show the full output of the error and what you did to cause it. We should be able to duplicate the result based on the information you provide.

Comment: I removed the line numbers from the code block in your question. If those numbers are actually in your code, they're probably the cause of problems.

Comment: Thanks, I put the line numbers in as a way to reference specific issues, but thank you.  No, I am not running numbers in the code. @FrankvanPuffelen

Comment: @DougStevenson I entered the two CLI commands I did to deploy, and then provided the errors.

Comment: What do you get by doing `node --version` in terminal window?

Comment: @RenaudTarnec: Hi, thanks for getting back to me.  I get this: v16.15.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You declare using node.js version 18 in the `package.json`:

```
engines": {
  "node": "18"
  }
```

but the installed version on your computer is 16.15.1.

You should adapt the `package.json` file as follows:

```
engines": {
  "node": "16"
  }
```

Comment: Hey @satchel, did my answer solved your problem?